# Linker error: switch to unicode build gives: unresolved external symbol WinMain

Tags: c++, unicode, cmake, visual-studio-2017, c++17

After switching all projects to Unicode(Character Set: Unicode), our solution on VS2017 gives the following linker error:

```
msvcrtd.lib(exe_winmain.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol WinMain
```

`WinMain` (or `wWinMain`) is the program entry point for graphical application. [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point).

Our projects are build using [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) and with setting `/D_UNICODE` unicode projects is generated. Before we didn't have a `WinMain` function in our own code (and shouldn't the linker try to link `wWinMain` instead for a unicode build). So, what are we missing here and what could possible cause this ?

---

Testing this with a default created mfc project, there is no issue between switching between between a unicode and non-unicode built.

---

Inserting `WinMain` manually seems to work, which I use as a workaround atm. , however I would prefer not do that (also this will conflict if I later switch back to non-unicode).

Comment: To those voting close: This question is **not** about seeking debugging help

Comment: "This question is not about seeking debugging help" - How else the question "what are we missing here?" could be interpreted? It could be that your project is wrong, and works with old settings only due to a luck. In any case, providing [mcve] would definitely improve your question.

Comment: Maybe try `/D_UNICODE` as the MSVC includes only ever look for this symbol as all uppercase?

Comment: @Tsyvarev making a minimal is easier said than done - please note im not saying this is bug in CMake or anything else for that matter, im just trying to understand why I get this linker error

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica when i wrote the post it was a mistake - _UNICODE was actually used

Comment: "Testing this with a default created mfc project, there is no issue between switching between between a unicode and non-unicode built." - So there is something special in your project which results in the error. Do you like a *guessing* game? We don't.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't like a guessing game - but I find this to be extremely strange and don't know where to start looking - after all there are a lot of settings and the reason could be simpel for someone with the right knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in cmake as per following. Try adding following to your CMakeLists.txt. It worked for me.

set (entry_point /ENTRY:wWinMainCRTStartup)

SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${entry_point}")

ref: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21202